# Mobile Menu Not Working

Tags: menus, mobile

The mobile menu stopped working after I updated WP to the latest version, I assume it has to do with a customization of the theme.

http://kvintage.com/

Wondering if anyone could please take a quick look and guide me through fixing this error!

The theme is Twenty Thirteen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I heard about this issue. Just try to disable jetpack mobile theme in your settings. Shut works. Best Regards

Comment: Hi, I actually have jetpack disabled so that isn't the issue. Something happened during customization, can't figure it out! Any other ideas? Thanks!